# Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice

Tags: angularjs

From the Docs:

> ## Embedding interpolation markup inside expressions
>
> > **Note:** AngularJS directive attributes take either expressions *or* interpolation markup with embedded expressions. It is considered **bad practice** to embed interpolation markup inside an expression:
>
> — [AngularJS Developer Guide - Interpolation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation)

I am looking for a well written canonical answer to which I can point readers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Docs:

> ## Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice:
>
> - It increases the complexity of the markup
> - There is no guarantee that it works for every directive, because interpolation itself is a directive. If another directive accesses attribute data before interpolation has run, it will get the raw interpolation markup and not data.
> - It impacts performance, as interpolation adds another watcher to the scope.
>
> [AngularJS Developer Guide - Interpolation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation)

Answer (score 4):

Directives which expect Boolean values won't work:

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> <input type="checkbox" ng-hide ="{{x.thenumber === null}}" />
> ```

When the expression evaluates to the Boolean value `false`, interpolation will return the string `"false"`. Strings that have length greater than zero are [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). The `ng-hide` directive will always hide and never show the input element.

CORRECT

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-hide="x.thenumber === null" />
```