# angular directive that's not working for error message

Tags: angularjs

*Directive is defined like this:*

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.directive("textBox", function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            name: "@",
            label: "@",
            id: "="
        },
        template: [
                    ' <div class="form-group">',
                    ' <label class="control-label" id="lbl{{name}}">{{label}}</label>',
                    ' <input id="txt{{name}}" class="form-control" ng-model="id" name="txt{{name}}" required />',
                    ' <span ng-show="myForm.txt{{name}}.$error.required" class="text-danger ">This field is required.</span>',
                    ' </div>'].join("")
    };
});
app.controller("registerController", function($scope, $http) {});
```

**My TAG**

**TAG**

```
<text-box label="user id *" name="userid" id="txtUserid"></text-box>
```

**directive for validation control...not showing error **

Comment: The `id` attribute is a reserved global attribute. It should not be used for an `ng-model` value.

Comment: You don't need to interpolate with `ngShow` directive, Use `ng-show="myForm['txt' + name].$error.required"`

Comment: @georgeawg i know that but my problem is that error message not working on my directive and everything going ok.

Comment: @georgeawg ☺okay ☺ according to you i replace id to Uid, ng-model bla bla...in our code now you give me answer

Comment: See [Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51592045/why-mixing-interpolation-and-expressions-is-bad-practice).

Comment: @georgeawg according to you ☻what is the best way to do same job

Comment: @georgeawg i solve it ☺    template: [
                    ' <div ng-form name="myForm" class="form-group">',
                    ' <label class="control-label" id="lbl{{name}}">{{label}}</label>',
                    ' <input id="txt{{name}}" class="form-control" ng-model="id" name="txt{{name}}" required />',
                    ' <span ng-show="myForm.txt{{name}}.$error.required" class="text-danger ">This field is required.</span>',
                    ' </div>'].join("")

Comment: If you solved the problem, write that as an answer. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.directive("textPan", function () {
    return {

        scope: {
            uname: "@",
            ulabel: "@",
            uid: "=",
            ureadonly: "@",

        },
        template: [
             ' <div ng-form name="myForm"  class="form-group">',
            ' <label class="control-label" id="{{uname}}">{{ulabel}}</label>',
            ' <input   id="{{uname}}" class="form-control" ng-model="val" name="{{uname}}"  ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]{1}$/" required />',
            ' <span ng-show="myForm.{{uname}}.$error.required" class="text-danger ">This field is required.</span>',
            '<span ng-show="myForm.{{uname}}.$error.pattern" class="text-danger">PAN number is not valid</span>',
         ,
            ' </div>'].join("")
    };
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="registerController">
 <text-pan ulabel="PAN #" uname="Pan" uid="txtPan"></text-pan>
 
 </div>
```