# Is it possible to add an ng-repeat $index value inside an ng-click with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

In my HTML I have a dropdown list that I did with an **ng-repeat.**
Each of these elements needs to have their own function when clicked, so I'm using **$index.** Here's part of my code:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu status-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
   <span class="dropdown-item active" ng-click="allItems()">All Items</span>
   <span ng-repeat="x in itemsArray" class="dropdown-item"
         ng-click="myFunction{{$index}}()">{{x.name}}</span>
</div>
```

When I inspect the element in the browser, it actually shows the items like this:

```
ng-click="myFunction0()", ng-click="myFunction1()", ng-click="myFunction2()", etc...
```

But when click on them, they don't work, and the console throws this error:

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 11 of the expression [myFunction{{$index}}()] starting at [{{$index}}()]

Got any idea on how can I make this work, or if there is a better approach?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use interpolation (`{{ }}`) inside AngularJS expressions. Instead use a property accessor:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu status-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
   <span class="dropdown-item active" ng-click="allItems()">All Items</span>
   <span ng-repeat="x in itemsArray" class="dropdown-item"
         ̶n̶g̶-̶c̶l̶i̶c̶k̶=̶"̶m̶y̶F̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶{̶{̶$̶i̶n̶d̶e̶x̶}̶}̶(̶)̶"̶
         ng-click="this['myFunction'+$index]()">
     {{x.name}}
   </span>
</div>
```

With AngularJS expressions, the `this` context is bound to $scope.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Expression context](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#context)
- [Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51592045/why-mixing-interpolation-and-expressions-is-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1):

Also you can solve it by pass **index** in one **function**:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dropdown-menu status-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
   <span class="dropdown-item active" ng-click="allItems()">All Items</span>
      <span ng-repeat="x in itemsArray" class="dropdown-item" 
            ng-click="myFunction($index)">{{x.name}}</span>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.myFunction(index){
   switch(index){
     case 0: 
        ///function 0
     break;
     case 1:
        ///function 1
     break;
     //etc
   }
}
```