# Is it possible to store AngularJS functions in arrays and put the functions in ng-click?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, function, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I was trying to make a few buttons using Array. The buttons displayed, but the function from the array is not working.

```js
var module = angular.module('app',[]);
module.controller('Ctrl',['$scope', function ($scope){
  $scope.data = [
  {link: "myNav.pushPage('page1')", btn:'Page 1'},
  {link: "myNav.pushPage('page2')", btn:'Page 2'},
  {link: "myNav.pushPage('page3')", btn:'Page 3'}
  ]
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
    <td><button ng-click="{{x.link}}">{{x.btn}}</button></td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: `ng-click` accepts expressions, so you don't need the interpolation syntax (i.e. `{{ ... }}`). Instead you can use `$eval` as part of the expression: `ng-click="$eval(x.link)"`.

Comment: Mixing interpolation (`{{ }}`) with AngularJS expressions is [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51592045/why-mixing-interpolation-and-expressions-is-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var module = angular.module('app',[]);
module.controller('Ctrl',['$scope', function ($scope){
    $scope.data = [
      {link: "page1", btn:'Page 1'},
      {link: "page2", btn:'Page 2'},
      {link: "page3", btn:'Page 3'}
    ]
    $scope.navigate(link){
    //$state.go(link) //navigate page
}
```

}]);

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
    <td><button ng-click="navigate(x.link)">{{x.btn}}</button></td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the function is always the same and only the parameter changes, you can have the parameter in `data` array and pass it like this:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
        <td><button ng-click="test(x.link)">{{x.btn}}</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

With this array:

```
$scope.data = [{
  link: "page1",
  btn: 'Page 1'
},
{
  link: "page2",
  btn: 'Page 2'
},
{
  link: "page3",
  btn: 'Page 3'
}]
```

Check a working demo: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5jLzd8qa/6/)

Comment: Thank Dude, I got it