# Angular JS - differentiating between a save and update with a common template

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a project with a PHP backend and Angular 1.x on the front end. I have a Listings model and I use a common template to create (add) and update (edit) a Listing.

Since eidt and add both use the same front end template I need to be able to detect when a user is creating and when they are editing. It seems there are several ways to do this:

1. I could pass a paramater in the ng-submit:

   ```
   ng-submit="saveListing({{isNewListing}}"
   ```

Then I could read the value of the paramter in my controller, but I think this is overkill?

2. When editing a Listing some variables set for the form auto-fill

   ```
   $scope.listing.id = x;
   ```

Therfore I could just check for a value in the above:

```
$scope.saveListing = function() {
    if(listing.id) {
         // update action
    } else {
         // save action
    }
};
```

Is the second option a sound and non-hacky approach. I am not an Angular pro so although it seems the logical approach to me I want to ensure that I am not hot woring this.

Comment: Don't use double curly brackets `{{ }}` with the `ng-submit` directive. See [Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51592045/why-mixing-interpolation-and-expressions-is-bad-practice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do something similar to the second approach. Since editing means you have to "get" the original record in most cases, the record should exist somewhere in the scope. I use ui-router and have a resolve for the record, which means I can check right at the top of the controller:

```
$scope.isEdit = record != null;
```

With a scope variable or similar (e.g. `controllerAs vm`) you can leverage the fact that you're in "edit mode" and change the UI up a bit. Instead of "+ New" on a button you can have "+ Save".

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

We have a large ERP system with angularJs as a front-end framework, and we are using the "check id" approach.
When updating/edit an item there would be existing id for that item.
I think the second approach is good and I don't see any drawbacks.