# How to evaluate the valid property on form with dynamic name in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

So I have a forms generated dynamically like this using angular JS. I am using `channel.tabNames` to make sure I dont end up with duplicate field names for multiple forms that are generated in a loop like this.

```
<form ng-repeat="channel in ctr.model.mediaChannels" 
      novalidate 
      id="{{channel.tabName}}form" 
      name="{{channel.tabName}}form"
```

I then have a field like this where I evaluate the field names to apply an error class for validation

```
<input type="text" 
       name="overrideComments{{channel.tabName}}" 
       ng-required="true" 
       ng-class="{'has-error':{{channel.tabName}}form.overrideComments{{channel.tabName}}.$invalid && {{channel.tabName}}form.$submitted}"
       ng-model="channel.mediaSummary.overrideComments" />
```

So far so good.. but when I want to pass the $valid property on the form to a method using ng-click I run into trouble..

```
<input class="btn btn-success p-2" type="submit" value="Add To Basket"
       ng-click="ctr.addToBasket(channel,{{channel.tabName}}form.$valid)" />
```

Which gives this error..

> Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 26 of the expression [ctr.addToBasket(channel,{{channel.tabName] starting at [{channel.tabName].

How else can I pass the `$valid` property of the form? I know I could use jquery validation on the angular controller.. but that adds its own messages and I would prefer to do this the angular way..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$index` property of `ng-repeat` for a unique id. Also it would be easier to have an array for all the forms and then access each form using the unique `$index` :

```
<form ng-repeat="channel in vm.data" novalidate id="form{{$index}}" name="vm.forms.form{{$index}}">

<input type="text" 
       name="overrideComments" 
       ng-required="true" 
       ng-class="{'has-error': vm.forms['form'+$index].overrideComments.$invalid 
       && vm.forms['form'+$index].$submitted}" 
       ng-model="overrideComments" />

<input class="btn btn-success p-2" 
       type="submit" 
       value="Add To Basket" 
       ng-click="vm.addToBasket($index)" />
```

In controller, you can keep an array of the forms, pass the index in the function and then check the validity of the associated form:

```
vm.forms = {};
vm.addToBasket = function(i) {
   console.log(i);
   console.log(vm.forms[`form${i}`].$invalid);

}
```

Check the working demo: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a5nkvc7r/)

Comment: That is very cool, I didnt realise you could bind an object on the controller to the form like that using the name.. very nice!

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using double curly brackets (`{{ }}`) in AngularJS expressions:

```
<input type="text" name="overrideComments" ng-required="true" 
    ng-class="{'has-error': ̶v̶m̶.̶f̶o̶r̶m̶s̶.̶f̶o̶r̶m̶{̶{̶$̶i̶n̶d̶e̶x̶}̶}̶.̶o̶v̶e̶r̶r̶i̶d̶e̶C̶o̶m̶m̶e̶n̶t̶s̶.̶$̶i̶n̶v̶a̶l̶i̶d̶
                            vm.forms['form'+$index].overrideComments.$invalid }" 
    ng-model="channel.mediaSummary.overrideComments" />
```

For more information, see

- [Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51592045/why-mixing-interpolation-and-expressions-is-bad-practice)